# Set an .htaccess file for every directory

Tags: .htaccess, subdomain, browser-cache, mod-expires, expires-header

I'm working on multiple subdomains on my domain. I just finished working on one and want to specify cache headers for this specific subdomain. I dont want the other subdomains to also enable the cache headers, just the single one i finished working on.

So, expire headers should work for subdomain A, but not for subdomain B and C.

I have no clue how to achieve this and can't find a similar question.

My current .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    # Enable expirations
    ExpiresActive On 
    # Default directive
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
    # My favicon
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
    # Images
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    # CSS
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
    # Javascript
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Do you have access to server config? vhosts?

Comment: I don't think I can access the server config. I pay for regular web hosting. All I know is that my domain is hosted using Apache/2.4.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `<If>` directive in htaccess context to match against the `HTTP_HOST` variable:

```
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ /(www\.)?subdomainA\.example\.com$/">
    # List of expires directives here
</If>
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for. Thanks